# How come multiple functions mapped to same address in Visual Studio link map?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm accustomed to seeing each module or function assigned a distinct adrress in a linker map. I don't understand why the linker is assigning the same address (**006539d0**) to multiple modules in this case:

```
> 0001:002529d0 ?bottom@DRECT@@QBEHXZ                    006539d0 f i pg_trellis.obj
> 0001:002529d0 ?getBottom@BIG_RECT@@QBEJXZ              006539d0 f i PG066.obj
> 0001:002529d0 ?MemAllocated@?$ARRAY@VcLineTr@@@@QBEJXZ 006539d0 f i pg_trellis.obj
> 0001:002529d0 ?get_fmt_idx@CellFormat@ExcelFormat@@QBEHXZ 006539d0 f i ExcelFormat.obj
> 0001:002529d0 ?base@cMapFile@@QAEPAXXZ                 006539d0 f i IE_talker.obj
> 0001:002529d0 ?getCurrAIsubject@cListBox@@QAEIXZ       006539d0 f i PG_SCROL.obj
> 0001:002529d0 ?rdstate@ios_base@std@@QBEHXZ            006539d0 f i BasicExcel.obj
> 0001:002529d0 ?NumItems@?$WBHash@PAVcDN@@@@QAEJXZ      006539d0 f i pg164.obj
```

There are other groups of functions sharing a same address. Most functions have unique addresses.

There is nothing unusual about these functions; they are separate and don't have anything in common. (**Edit: wrong: they are identical**).

How am I supposed to decipher a stack trace, and determine which function was in play?

I'm using Visual Studio 2010; Windows 7. It's a 32-bit Win32 project.

Edit: I spoke too soon without examining the details. Indeed the functions are almost identical:

```
class DRECT
{   private:
    RECT m_rect;

    inline int bottom(void) const           // get
    {   return m_rect.bottom;   // a LONG in tagRECT (Win32)
    }
}

class BIG_RECT : private tagRECT
{
    inline LONG getBottom(void) const
    {   return bottom;  // a LONG in tagRECT (Win32)
    }
}

struct CellFormat
{   int get_fmt_idx() const
    {   return _fmt_idx;    // an int
    }
}

class cListBox
{   inline PG_PIN getCurrAIsubject(void)
    {   return m_currAISubject;     // an unsigned int
    }
}

template <class T> class ARRAY
{   inline ARLONG MemAllocated() const
    {   return num_elems;       // a long
    }
}
```

I suppose I have to look at the calling function in the stack to determine which particular function is being called.

Comment: Are they all of the form `something *func_name() {return this->something;}` by any chance? If several functions compile to exactly the same machine code, then they can be merged.

Comment: No, they are all very different. There are several other groups that share the same address, a different address.

Comment: Can you show the code for at least two of them, so I can see for myself?

Comment: You are correct: I added the function definitions in the post block above. My apologies, I should have examined the details. They just sounded so different  :o) And some of them I wrote twenty years ago. Thanks very much.